# Overflow:hidden not working on any Android Device Mobile App

Tags: html, css, android-layout, mobile

I am using CSS property overflow:hidden(overflow-y:hidden; / overflow-x:hidden;) to stop the body scrolling on mobile app. It's working on mobile Browser, but this code is not working on any Android Device.

```
body {
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following line in your html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height">
```